# How to make generic type ArrayList static?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, static, generic-type-argument

I have the following ArrayList :

```
public ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I want to share its value with other classes, But when I define it as static it gives me the following error :

```
'Packagename.Class.this' Cannot be referenced from a static context.
```

So does anyone know how to make it static or how to share its value with other classes in any other way?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a fuller example?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik I have a class that add objects to the above list and in another class I have a thread that waits for the list to be filled, So I want to get the same value of the list when I check it from the thread.

Comment: Then the thread will need a reference to the containing instance so it can get the correct reference from that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the <E> on a static property definition because the <E> will be defined differently for each instance of the class. Consider, for example the following snippet:

```
public class A<E> {
    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<String> a1 = new A<>();
        A<Integer> a2 = new A<>();
    }
}
```

... as you can see, the 'list' needs to take different generic types for each instance of A. A static List would make no sense as it would need to be of both types simultaneously.

The fact that it has to be tied to a specific instance should probably cause you to rethink what you are trying to do in sharing the value with other classes.